# The best pattern to register many function callback handlers in C?

Tags: c, design-patterns

I am writing a module for AT command parser, and in the AT_Parser `struct`, I have a list of callback that I would like to make.

When creating the `AT_Parser` instance, I need to register all the function callback handler in my `at_parser_create` method by passing as function parameter.

The example is shown below:

```
// at_parser.h

typedef void (*At_Handler)(uint8_t *src);

typedef struct {
  At_Handler echo;
  At_Handler data;
  At_Handler device_profile;
  At_Handler parameter_setting;
  At_Handler error;
} AT_Parser;

AT_Parser *at_parser_create(At_Handler *echo, At_Handler *data,
                   At_Handler *device_profile, At_Handler *parameter_setting,
                   At_Handler *error);

// at_parser.c

AT_Parser *at_parser_create(At_Handler *echo, At_Handler *data,
                   At_Handler *device_profile, At_Handler *parameter_setting,
                   At_Handler *error) 
{
  AT_Parser *instance = malloc(sizeof(*instance));
  instance->echo = echo;
  instance->data= data;
  instance->device_profile= device_profile;  
  instance->parameter_setting= parameter_setting;  
  instance->error= error;

  return instance;
}

// main.c

static void at_handler_echo(uint8_t *src) {}
static void at_handler_data(uint8_t *src) {}
static void at_handler_device_profile(uint8_t *src) {}
static void at_handler_parameter_setting(uint8_t *src) {}
static void at_handler_error(uint8_t *src) {}

int main(void)
{
  AT_Parser *at_parser = at_parser_create(at_handler_echo, at_handler_data,
                            at_handler_device_profile, at_handler_parameter_setting,
                            at_handler_error);
}
```

You could see from the example above, this solution is not elegant and clean, if I would have more function callback in my `AT_Parser` struct, I would need to have more parameters in my `at_parser_create` method.

Is there any better design pattern or solution to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't scale"? The C compiler should be able to handle a large number of parameters. In the source, you can break the function call over several lines so the parameters are easier to see.

Comment: Presumably, you've not finished your editing with `instance->echo = echo;
  instance->echo = data;
  instance->echo = device_profile;  
  instance->echo = parameter_setting;  
  instance->echo = error;` (too many assignments to `echo` and not enough to the other members).

Comment: How about a single callback that takes two parameters? The first parameter is the `type`: echo, data, profile, etc. The second parameter is `*src`.

Comment: The only other option is to wrap the parameters in yet another struct. But then you may want a function to initialize it ... But lots of libraries take a (pointer to) a struct of options in the init functions.

Comment: @luserdroog i have edited my question, i use the wrong word of scale.., what i want to say is in that function, it will have a lots of parameters and that doesnt look good

Comment: I think maybe that was the correct word. I think the answer is "it's ok, it won't break anything to have lots of parameters" up to some large limit I forget, several hundred I expect.

Comment: @user3386109 yup that makes sense, but i would like to have a callback handler for each `type`, and how to solve this multi parameter in function method..

Comment: Did you consider an array?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how would that be?

Comment: You have a long list of callbacks, all with the same signature.  You can create an array with the callbacks listed in the correct order — maybe using designated initializers. (`enum { AT_ECHO, AT_DATA, …, AT_ERROR }; At_handler handlers[] = { [AT_ECHO] = at_echo, [AT_DATA] = at_data, …, [AT_ERROR] = at_error };` and pass `handlers` to the function. You can revise the structure so it uses an array.  And you can pass the array as a single argument.  Or go with what you're doing — unless you're planning to get to many tens of entries (or more), it is moderately tidy.